# Proper steps of data processing in an IoT cloud platform development

Tags: data-transfer, system-architecture

We are developing an IoT cloud platform with known components like Cloud Gateway, Stream Processing, Device Shadowing, etc...

The question is what is the proper sequence of locating pre-validation of incoming device data (maybe there is no need to do this first!) and updating device shadow.

And could you give me some advice what is the best path of data from the creation to completion.

- Cloud gateway — MQTT broker from device sensor data first to ingest data to Apache Kafka.
- Device shadow service — which holds latest states of devices in the cloud side of platform that users can be informed about the latest state of their devices — (this service is using event sourcing method which stores all sensor data as well)

Comment: What does 'proper sequence of locating pre-validation of incoming device data' mean? What do you want to validate? What kind of data? What do you want to locate?

Comment: @Helmar from the creation to the storage of the device sensor data, could you give me summary advices **how/where to** "validate my sensor data is valid or not", "update my device shadow/twin to store latest state somewhere", "process if there is a rule defined on the device in Apache Flink or Spark" and "**when to** store into Cassandra for analytics later use".  Thanks

Comment: That sounds like an enormous task with very little information to go on. I'd suggest you pick one of the areas validation, device shadow or persistence layer for the question and add some question parameters to get a good answer. Parameters could be expected regional distribution (my garden vs global), number of devices, amount of shared device data (bits or TB), complexity of device shadow (on/off vs. everything in an airplane) et cetera, otherwise the usefulness of any answer will be rather  little and the question probably closed as too broad.

Comment: If you add these information please do not answer with a comment but [edit] them directly into your question.